# How to remove anything after a non-slash character in a string?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

The problem I am encountering is strange. Suppose I have:

```
 a = "www.XXXXXXX.com"
 b = "www.XXXXXXX.com/laskdfj/=*&9809f/12-613"
 c = "www.XXXX.comllkjldfjlsadjfjldsf"
 d = "http://www.XXXX.CoMmasldfjl"
 e = "www.XXX.us/sdf"
 f = "www.XXX.us0948klsdf"
```

If following after the ".com" or ".us" is not a slash, then remove it. So the result would be like:

```
 a = "www.XXXXXXX.com"
 b = "www.XXXXXXX.com/laskdfj/=*&9809f/12-613"
 c = "www.XXXX.com"
 d = "http://www.XXXX.CoM"
 e = "www.XXX.us/sdf"
 f = "www.XXX.us"
```

Regular expression is new to me, and I read several blogs about regular expression, none of them seem to talk about how to use if-statement to handle my situation... any hints?

Comment: It's perfectly normal to look for an if statement (and there are if statements in regex). However, you don't need a special construct here, a simple match would suffice. If you're interested in learning regex, I suggest this tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize `sub` for this task:

```
sub('(.*\\.(?i:com|us))[^/]+', '\\1', x)
```

If you're wanting a more general approach, you can use:

```
sub('(.*\\.[[:alpha:]]{2,3})[^/]*', '\\1', x)
```

<kbd>[**CodeBunk**](http://codebunk.com/pb/86955369)</kbd>

Comment: Elegant! I tried to use "[:alpha:]{2,3}" to replace the "com|us" part to make it become more general... but it looks like I didn't get the right syntax...

Comment: Actually what does "?1:com|us" mean in your solution, I tried sub('(.*\\.(?i:[[:alpha:]]{2,3}))[^/]+', '\\1', x) but it is wrong, what is a right way to write it?

Comment: `(?i: ... )` is a case-insensitive group construct to combine expressions.